# Why empty stdin with EOF

Tags: c

there are many questions about flushing stdin, mine is not about how to flush it, rather about the meaning of the following function:

```
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

I am trying to think of scenarios why and how we would need EOF in this function for emptying stdin? The user types something and presses enter, and we empty the buffer until we find enter, where does EOF come in?

Thank you

Edit: 
Thank you very much for the first answer and the second comment, that answers my question and totally satisfies me.

Other than the scenario where we pipe our input from a file where we have a real EOF, which pretty much answered my question, I still do not understand why we would need EOF in any other scenario for a function like this. the user can only invoke EOF at the beginning of a line in the terminal, so it cannot be used for emptying the buffer.

Comment: You don't flush `stdin` with `EOF`, that code is just reading all the characters from `stdin` and discards them, it depends on where that code is, I mean the context. If you for example use `scanf()` to read a value and input a valid value followed by spaces, that code will remove all the spaces from the input buffer.

Comment: Consider the scenario where the shell is piping input from a file into your application's STDIN...

Comment: For completeness, you may want to post the type of `c` which should be `int` and not `char`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the user inserts Ctrl-D (on Linux/OS X) or Ctrl-Z (on Windows), you get an EOF from stdin. Also, the standard input may be redirected from a file - in that case, at the end you get a "real" EOF.

In both these cases, without that check that loop would go on forever, waiting for a newline that will never come (insert melancholic music here).

Comment: Thanks, Other than the scenario where we pipe our input from a file where we have a real EOF, which pretty much answered my question, I still do not understand why we would need EOF in any other scenario for a function like this. the user can only invoke EOF at the beginning of a line in the terminal, so it cannot be used for emptying the buffer.

Comment: @Mcs, *users* may not need to send EOF, but *your program* should account for the possibility that it will get one.

Comment: @Mcs: that depends entirely on the terminal emulator; on my Linux machine, xterm, Konsole and all the virtual consoles happily accepts a first Ctrl-D mid-line as an stdin flush, and the next one (still on the same line) as an EOF.

Answer (score 4):

Your code does not "flush" `stdin`. All it does is searching for the nearest `'\n'`, or the end of the input, whichever comes first.

You can get an `EOF` in several situations:

- End-user presses a combination that closes `stdin`, meaning that the next attempt to read would return `EOF`, or
- You hit the actual end-of-file, when the input is redirected through OS-specific means to access a file instead of using console, e.g. `a.out <data.txt`
- There is a read error in the middle of accessing the input stream of your program.

The reasons why you may do it could be different, but most often it's clearing out the leftovers from some previous invalid input.

Comment: okay, this code flushes stdin: do c = getchar(); while (c != EOF && c!= '\n'); second when I press control+z in windows nothing happens unless I write a program that says something should happen, and for that I need to read EOF anyway

Comment: @Mcs That's the thing with `EOF`, it does not come to you until you ask for it. Pressing Ctrl+z does not "send" an `EOF`, it just tells the console to mark the input stream closed. At this point, nothing else can get into the stream, but the characters that are there already would remain there. So if you enter `hello` before pressing Ctrl+z, and the program reads the first three characters, the other two characters would remain in the buffer for your program to read.

Comment: thanks @dasblinkenlight I guess I will go with a bit more trial and error to really grasp what is going on:)

Answer (score 1):

The statement you present reads the remainder of the current line from `stdin` and discards it, whether the line ends with a newline character (`'\n'`) or at the end of the stream (`EOF`).  As dasblinkenlight observes, that is not what is conventionally called a "flush".

`getchar()` returns `EOF` at the end of the stream or on error, and `EOF != '\n'`, so without the the `EOF` check, that statement would loop infinitely if it reaches the end of the stream.

It is by no means certain that the last line of the input will be newline-terminated.  In fact, you could argue that the last line of a stream is the one terminated by the end of the stream, so the last line is *never* newline-terminated, though it may contain zero characters.

Comment: but why would a user type something and then do control-z enter, it just doesn't make sense to me, the user can ONLY invoke EOF in the beginning of a line anyway, I don't get it, maybe I still don't get how EOF works

Comment: @Mcs That's not true that end-users can "invoke EOF in the beginning of a line", you can press it at any time, right in the middle of a word.

Comment: @Mcs, dasblinkenlight described two scenarios in which the program might encounter an `EOF` on `stdin`.  A third, related one occurs when the output of one program is "piped" to the input of another.  In any case, it is a poor practice for a program to assume that its inputs will take only the form it wants.  A robust program accounts for all possibilities.

Comment: thanks @dasblinkenlight a lot of misinformation is going on here, I remember reading that you can't invoke EOF in the middle of a line today